# Huwaei Honor V9 dual camera capture at the same time

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

The Huwaei Honor V9 has two back cameras. It also has a third-selfie-camera that is not relevant at this time for me. One of the cameras is color and one is black and white.
I can take a picture from the color camera and black and white camera one after the other by toggling the EFFECT_MONO flag. Is it possible to capture from both of them at exactly the same time?